# vector outer product squared identity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof for the *rank-one perturbation of the identity* and everywhere I look the following statement is always used

> for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ , $xy^T xy^T$ is $xy^T$ multiplied by the scalar $y^T x$. In other words  $xy^T xy^T = (y^T x ) xy^T$.

Can someone help me show this claim or redirect me to somewhere where it's explained, I can't get it right for the life of me, I tried taking the transpose or rearranging with no success.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that you are just applying the associative property of matrix multiplication to get $x (y^T x) y^T$. Then you use the commutative property of scalar-matrix multiplication to move the scalar part outside: $(y^T x) x y^T$

Comment: sasquires comment is the way to think about this. Also note $y^Tx$ is just a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $xy^T$ is a matrix. Summing repeated indices,$$[(xy^T)^2]_{ij}=(xy^T)_{ik}(xy^T)_{kj}=x_i\underbrace{y_kx_k}_{y\cdot x}y_j=(y\cdot x)(xy^T)_{ij},$$i.e. $(xy^T)^2=(y\cdot x)(xy^T)$.